# Bootstrap Carousel bounces, unable to edit it with HTML and CSS - O/P gif included

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

incorrect output:

[image]

If you see keenly when the carousel moves from almond 2 to almond 3 there is this small jump happens, I tried to remove in all way but I couldnt remove it. To show the output I have attached the pencode link. you can see the result here https://codepen.io/gladwin-james/pen/oNYWJxL and also uploaded the above GIF for clear expalnation. I have also shared the same code I shared in pencode

**HTML**

```
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />

    <!-- About nuts - Slider-->
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="centering_the_slider_contents">
              <!-- Nut 1-->
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <figure class="images_in_nuts">
                  <img src="images/almonds.jpg" />
                </figure>
                <div class="nut_text">
                  <h2>Almond</h2>
                  <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
                  <p>
                    Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
                    Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
                    Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
                    phenolic acids
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Nut 1 Ends-->
              <!-- Nut 2-->
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <figure class="images_in_nuts">
                  <img src="images/almonds.jpg" />
                </figure>
                <div class="nut_text">
                  <h2>Almond 2</h2>
                  <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
                  <p>
                    Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
                    Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
                    Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
                    phenolic acids
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Nut 2 Ends-->
              <!-- Nut 3-->
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <figure class="images_in_nuts">
                  <img src="images/almonds.jpg" />
                </figure>
                <div class="nut_text">
                  <h2>Almond 3</h2>
                  <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
                  <p>
                    Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
                    Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
                    Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
                    phenolic acids
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Nut 3 Ends-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
          src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
        
        <!-- Everything Related to nuts ends here - Slider Ends-->
      
        <div class="last_contact_us" id="last_contact_us">
          <p class="footer_contact_us">Contact Us</p>
          <p class="footer_contact_us_expl">
            Call us to get Nuts and Spices at a best quality <br />
            and also at a best price
          </p>
        </div>
    <script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
          src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script
          src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
.centering_the_slider_contents {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: -25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px auto;
  background: #ebebeb;
  display: flex;
 
}

.images_in_nuts {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nut_text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

// .last_contact_us {
//   background: #ffffff !important;
// }

.footer_contact_us  {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.footer_contact_us_expl {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}
```

I couldnt remove that jumb if you could help me with a solution it will really really helpful.

. By adding padding-top 15px; I am trying to get this small spacing

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.about_nuts {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.our_services_expl {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  
}

.carousel-item
{
margin:20px 0px;

}

.centering_the_slider_contents {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ebebeb;
  display: flex;
 }

.images_in_nuts {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nut_text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

// .last_contact_us {
//   background: #ffffff !important;
// }

.footer_contact_us  {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.footer_contact_us_expl {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}
```

```html
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
<div class="about_nuts_main" id="section_about_nuts_main">
    <p class="about_nuts">About Nuts</p>
    <p class="our_services_expl">
        Dont Feel Shy Choose your Favourite Nut and get to know <br/>
        what's inside about it
    </p>
</div>
<!-- About nuts - Slider-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="centering_the_slider_contents">
            <!-- Nut 1-->
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <figure class="images_in_nuts">
                    <img src="images/almonds.jpg" />
                </figure>
                <div class="nut_text">
                    <h2>Almond</h2>
                    <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
                    <p>
                        Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
                        Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
                        Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
                        phenolic acids
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Nut 1 Ends-->
            <!-- Nut 2-->
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <figure class="images_in_nuts">
                    <img src="images/almonds.jpg" />
                </figure>
                <div class="nut_text">
                    <h2>Almond 2</h2>
                    <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
                    <p>
                        Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
                        Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
                        Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
                        phenolic acids
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Nut 2 Ends-->
            <!-- Nut 3-->
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <figure class="images_in_nuts">
                    <img src="images/almonds.jpg" />
                </figure>
                <div class="nut_text">
                    <h2>Almond 3</h2>
                    <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
                    <p>
                        Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium,
                        Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br />
                        Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br />
                        phenolic acids
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Nut 3 Ends-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
    <script
        src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Everything Related to nuts ends here - Slider Ends-->
<div class="last_contact_us" id="last_contact_us">
    <p class="footer_contact_us">Contact Us</p>
    <p class="footer_contact_us_expl">
        Call us to get Nuts and Spices at a best quality <br />
        and also at a best price
    </p>
</div>
<script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

Remove padding-top from **.centering_the_slider_contents** to fix bounce and add top+bottom margin on **.carousel-item** for space.

Comment: hey bro if you could find time can you please help me with this problem Please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291637/contents-gets-overlapped-in-mobile-view-in-html-and-css

Answer (score 1):

You have conflicting parameters:

1. Two margin top with different spacing and an auto function on it (this one isn't needed);
2. Padding-top that conflicts with the two margins;

I changed your code and it's perfect

Here is the [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/lucassaladini/pen/wvoeVKq) code

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.centering_the_slider_contents {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: -25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 15px auto;
  background: #ebebeb;
  display: flex;
}

.images_in_nuts {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nut_text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

// .last_contact_us {
//   background: #ffffff !important;
// }
.footer_contact_us {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.footer_contact_us_expl {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<!-- About nuts - Slider-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="centering_the_slider_contents">
      <!-- Nut 1-->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <figure class="images_in_nuts">
          <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/79284525.cms?width=680&height=512&imgsize=134959" />
        </figure>
        <div class="nut_text">
          <h2>Almond</h2>
          <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
          <p>
            Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium, Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br /> Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br /> phenolic acids
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Nut 1 Ends-->
      <!-- Nut 2-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <figure class="images_in_nuts">
          <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/79284525.cms?width=680&height=512&imgsize=134959" />
        </figure>
        <div class="nut_text">
          <h2>Almond 2</h2>
          <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
          <p>
            Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium, Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br /> Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br /> phenolic acids
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Nut 2 Ends-->
      <!-- Nut 3-->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <figure class="images_in_nuts">
          <img src="https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/79284525.cms?width=680&height=512&imgsize=134959" />
        </figure>
        <div class="nut_text">
          <h2>Almond 3</h2>
          <h3 class="rich_in">Rich In</h3>
          <p>
            Vitamin E, Monounsaturated fats, Fiber, Biotin, <br />Calcium, Phosphorus, Magnesium, Copper, <br /> Phytonutrients, specifically flavonoids, plant sterols,<br /> phenolic acids
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Nut 3 Ends-->
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Everything Related to nuts ends here - Slider Ends-->

<div class="last_contact_us" id="last_contact_us">
  <p class="footer_contact_us">Contact Us</p>
  <p class="footer_contact_us_expl">
    Call us to get Nuts and Spices at a best quality <br /> and also at a best price
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I have already tried this and then I added .centering_the_slider_contents { padding-top: 15px;} and still the issue presists. I am trying to give a small space above the segment  scroll, like a space which comes when padding is added https://codepen.io/gladwin-james/pen/oNYWJxL

Comment: I just removed the `padding-top: 15px` and stopped the "bounce"

Comment: Yes, but If that padding-top: 15px is removed a small space is removed, I added another picture in my question for a reference can you check it. so if padding-top: 15px is removed the space disappears, I want that small space when padding is added the bounce happens.

Comment: I'll edit the original answer with the new solution I got