# Contents gets overlapped in mobile view in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]The code works correctly in desktop view but when I try to shrink the browser the over lap happens. I have provided the @media queries but still the contents overlaps with each other, this is the codepen link https://codepen.io/gladwin-james/pen/jOVLZeO you can notice the difference if you shrink the browser

I have also shared the code below

**HTML and CSS**

```css
.navbar2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins" !important;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar2_for_mobile {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.products {
  background: #e1e1e2;
}

.our_products_are_nuts {
  margin-top: -50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nuts_expl {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .navbar2 {
    visibility: collapse;
  }


  .navbar2_for_mobile {
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Poppins" !important;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="navbar2">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <a href="#section_products">Products</a>
      <span class="the_line"> | </span>
      <a href="#section_products_services">Services</a>
      <span class="the_line"> | </span>
      <a href="#section_about_nuts_main">About Nuts</a>
      <span class="the_line"> | </span>
      <a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- navbar2_for_mobile -->

<div class="navbar2_for_mobile">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <a href="#section_products">Products</a>
      <span class="the_line"> | </span>
      <a href="#section_products_services">Services</a>
      <span class="the_line"> | </span>
      <a href="#section_about_nuts_main">About Nuts</a> <br>
      <!-- <span class="the_line"> | </span> -->
      <a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="products" id="section_products">
  <p class="our_products_are_nuts">Our Products Are Nuts <br>& Spice</p>
  <p class="nuts_expl">
    Call us to get Nuts and Spices at a best quality <br />
    and also at a best price
  </p>
</div>
```

it will be really helpful if could share if there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written very lengthy code for a very simple thing, but sticking to your code, just replace your
"visibility: collapse" with "display: none"
and
"visibility: visible" with "display: block", in your code.
Your working CSS code is like this:

```css
.navbar2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins" !important;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar2_for_mobile {
  display: none
}

.products {
  background: #e1e1e2;
}

.our_products_are_nuts {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nuts_expl {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .navbar2 {
    display:none
  }


  .navbar2_for_mobile {
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Poppins" !important;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
}
```

**Edit: -** Also remove "margin-top: -50px and -100px" from your code.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer, just a small clarification. So how can I plan to write a code simple insted of adding more code lines and making the program lengthy. I am new to programming, any idea will be really helpful.

Comment: Everybody needs a lot of practice to write a code that is not lengthy, so keep patience and keep practising. If you are new to website development, I will recommend you to start with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navbar2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Poppins" !important;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.navbar2_for_mobile {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.products {
  background: #e1e1e2;
  padding:10px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.our_products_are_nuts {
  
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Poppins";
  font-weight: bold;
}
.nuts_expl {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Poppins";
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .navbar2 {
    visibility: collapse;
  }


  .navbar2_for_mobile {
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Poppins" !important;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
  }
 .products {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar2">
      <div class="container">
        <p>
          <a href="#section_products">Products</a>
          <span class="the_line"> | </span>
          <a href="#section_products_services">Services</a>
          <span class="the_line"> | </span>
          <a href="#section_about_nuts_main">About Nuts</a>
          <span class="the_line"> | </span>
          <a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- navbar2_for_mobile -->

    <div class="navbar2_for_mobile">
      <div class="container">
        <p>
          <a href="#section_products">Products</a>
          <span class="the_line"> | </span>
          <a href="#section_products_services">Services</a>
          <span class="the_line"> | </span>
          <a href="#section_about_nuts_main">About Nuts</a> <br>
          <!-- <span class="the_line"> | </span> -->
          <a href="#contact_us">Contact Us</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="products" id="section_products">
      <p class="our_products_are_nuts">Our Products Are Nuts <br>& Spice</p>
      <p class="nuts_expl">
        Call us to get Nuts and Spices at a best quality <br />
        and also at a best price
      </p>
    </div>
```